# From SOQL, Truncate Id 18 to 15 - Cased Correctly?

Tags: soql, id

If I query for a record and get back its Id, I get 18 characters. However, support has informed me that for the purposes of testing, the `setProcessDefinitionNameOrId` [method](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_ProcessSubmitRequest.htm#apex_Approval_ProcessSubmitRequest_setProcessDefinitionNameOrId) will only work with a 15 digit Id. So let's say I have the following:

```
Id PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID = [
    SELECT Id FROM ProcessDefinition
    WHERE TableEnumOrId = 'My_Object__c'
    AND DeveloperName = 'My_Process'
    LIMIT 1
].Id;
String PROCESS_DEFINITION_TRUNCATED_ID = String.valueOf(PROCESS_DEFINITION_ID)
    .subString(0, 15);
```

Will `PROCESS_DEFINITION_TRUNCATED_ID` be correctly cased?

Comment: I would think so.

Comment: It seems to be the case (pardon the pun) so far in my testing. I would just like a conclusive answer other than "probably."

Comment: The docs here https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004383&language=en_US, states "The case-insensitive ID is identical to the 15-character case-sensitve ID with three extra characters appended to indicate teh case of each of the original 15 characters." and "If you need to convert the 18-characterID to a 15-character version, truncate the last three characters."

Comment: @JennyB You should post that as an answer. It's the most credible reference so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004383&language=en_US), states "The case-insensitive ID is identical to the 15-character case-sensitve ID with three extra characters appended to indicate teh case of each of the original 15 characters." and "If you need to convert the 18-characterID to a 15-character version, truncate the last three characters."

Answer (score 7):

Yes. When salesforce provides the 18 character version they do so in a case-aware way. This means that `substring` is a perfectly sane way to get the 15 character variant *as long as you haven't passed it through something not case aware*.

As an aside the same is true in apex - converting the `Id` type to a String gets you an 18 character string, and `substring` is the appropriate way to get it into it's 15 character format.

Comment: Thanks! This confirms my observations but do you have any documentation on that before I mark as accepted? Also, it sounds like even if I went through a case insensitive process, calling `Id.valueOf` and `substring` together should always yield a valid 15 digit `Id`?

Comment: You'd think, but it seems `Id.valueOf` doesn't fixup the case like you'd expect. This code fails for example: https://gist.github.com/capeterson/620a29b9e1474d9909b8

Comment: re: docs, don't have anything handy, and from that gist I'm a bit less confident than I was 5 minutes ago about general use correctness, but when *salesforce code* generates the Id it's going to always have the proper case. It's just not a contract the primitive apex types enforce for user-created `Id` instances.